# Uncaught reference error when trying to create basic wordpress ajax plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I have a custom Wordpress plugin. I am running into an error: "er=1:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: at_thm_ajax_obj is not defined at HTMLInputElement". I am not sure if I need to add to the wp-admin/ajax.php file or somewhere else.

The directory folder is wp-content/plugins/'at-thm-medicarelookup', here is the function file 'at-thm-medicarelookup.php':

```
<?php
/*
 *
 * Plugin Name: Medicare Member ID Lookup
 * Description: Custom plugin for Medicare Member ID Lookup
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Adrian Townsend
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

// First register resources with init
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'at_thm_medicarelookup_resource');
function at_thm_medicarelookup_resource() {
  wp_enqueue_script('at-thm-medicarelookup-script', plugins_url('js/at-thm-medicarelookupscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
  wp_enqueue_style('at-thm-medicarelookup-style', plugins_url('css/at-thm-medicarelookupstyle.css', __FILE__), array(), "1.0", "all");

  wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'at_thm_ajax_obj', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('at_thm_nonce'),
  ));
}

function at_thm_medicarelookupajax() {
  $response = 'Found it';
  echo wp_json_encode( $response );
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_at_thm_medicarelookup', 'at_thm_medicarelookupajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_at_thm_medicarelookup', 'at_thm_medicarelookupajax');
```

Here's the jquery file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('#thm_member-verify').click(function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    _ajax_nonce: at_thm_ajax_obj.nonce,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: at_thm_ajax_obj.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action:  "at_thm_medicarelookupajax",
      memberId: document.getElementById('input_25_10_6').value
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error. Correct way for wp_localize_script... `wp_localize_script('at-thm-medicarelookup-script', 'at_thm_ajax_obj', array(...));`